# Using script resource Trianglify in Ember route to modify DOM

Tags: javascript, ember.js, trianglify

I am learning Ember, and have hit a roadblock when it comes to using an script dependency in my ember route.  I have included the bower dependency [Trianglify.js](http://qrohlf.com/trianglify/) in my application using `app.import()` in `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
app.import('bower_components/trianglify/dist/trianglify.min.js');
```

I want to use this script to modify the background on my home route template.  I would like the background effect to be applied to an element on my home page.  I will either add a custom class to the output container of my home route, or target the global `.ember-view` div for now just to get it working.

I am realizing how little I know about how Ember,and am pretty confused as to how I achieve this functionality.  When I try to import Trianglify into my `home.js` route like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Trianglify from 'Trianglify';

var pattern = Trianglify({
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  cell_size: 90,
  variance: 1,
  stroke_width: 0.6,
  color_function : function(x, y) {
    return '#de6551';
  }
}).svg();

export default Ember.Route.extend({
});
```

I get the error:

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module `Trianglify` imported from `site/routes/home`
```

I am unsure where the scripts go when I `app.import()` them, and how I can then use those scripts elsewhere in my application to modify the presentation of elements in certain views.  How do I import this script for use in other JS files?  How do I reference it?

Also, since components are what we should be using, would I create a custom wrapper component for this route and import Trainglify into that file since components are the what should dictate view layer concerns?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround using [`ember-browserify`](https://github.com/ef4/ember-browserify).

just run 
`npm install --save-dev ember-browserify trianglify`

and then import via

`import Trianglify from 'npm:trianglify';`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.  This worked very well.  Also, I created a Trianglify component and hooked into the `didInsertElement` method to trigger off my functionality.  Thanks for the helpful nudge :)